# How to add items to a np.zeros array iteratively?

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a large np.zeros array as follows:

```
x = np.zeros((29316, 288, 512, 3))
```

The array stores images (29316 images with height/width of 288/512 and 3 R/G/B color channels. I'd now like to populate this array with images, one by one and don't want to keep track of the index. How can I insert images one after another?

To be clear, the images would go in at x[0], x[1], x[2] etc. Whenever an image is added it should go to the first spot where there isn't a np.zeros array.

Comment: "I'd now like to populate this array with images, one by one and don't want to keep track of the index" - this sounds like a situation where you should probably just keep track of the index.

Comment: @user2357112 yep, that's what I'm thinking ... that is essentially trivial. One thing computers are good at is counting up by one and keeping track of that count...

Comment: kay, thought there'd be a cleaner way. will do!